# How can i show 10 records in each column and then remaining show on next column automatically in a while loop?

Tags: php, mysql

This code is showing all the list in single column. I want i show 10 entries in one column and then 10 on next column and so on...

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 visible-lg visible-md visible-sm">
<?php
    include('include/connect.php');
    $result = mysql_query("select * from sub_cats", $con);
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
        echo "&raquo; <a href='#'>$row[sub_cat]</a> ($row[id])<br>";
    }
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Limit your query upto 10 records and paginate your records

Comment: no. you missunderstand. I want show one column and when 10 recoreds are completed and then show next column autometically.

Comment: mate....did my solution solved your problem??or are u still stucked somewhere???

Answer (score 2):

use `mod` to get count in multiples of 10....then simply echo `<br />` there

```
<?php
                include('include/connect.php');
                $result = mysql_query("select * from sub_cats", $con);
                $ten_multiple= 0;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                     /* assign new line after every 10 records
                        print <br /> after condition validation */
                    if(++$ten_multiple % 10 ==0) {echo '<br />';} 
                    echo "&raquo; <a href='#'>$row[sub_cat]</a> ($row[id])<br>";
                }
 ?>
```

Comment: You are missing a `$` between `++` and `ten_multiple`